# My samsung np-r580 wont boot windows 10 after memory upgrade

Tags: windows-10, boot, memory

So recently I bought 2 4gb ddr3 ram sticks that are compatible with my Samsung np-r580-jbb1us notebook, but when I installed them into my notebook it wouldn't boot windows. The bios detects both of them and it still boots when I put the old ones back in. Idk what happening, if someone could help that would be nice

Comment: Try https://www.memtest86.com/

Comment: Are you aware of what "ESD" is, and how to mitigate / prevent such damage? -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_discharge